# Return concrete objects based on generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I'm working with a third-party class like the following:

```
public class RepositoryGroup
{
    public StringRepository StringRepository { get; set; } //implements IRepository<string>
    public IntRepository IntRepository { get; set; } //implements IRepository<int>
}
```

I'd like to create a generic GetRepository method:

```
public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>(RepositoryGroup group)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) return (IRepository<T>)group.StringRepository;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) return (IRepository<T>)group.IntRepository;
}
```

But this won't work, because the compiler is not "smart" enough to note that `T` is `string` because of the condition.

Is there any way to coerce the compiler into recognizing or ignoring this? I know I can do it with reflection, but I'd rather not (mainly for readability).

Comment: `return (IRepository<T>)(object)group.StringRepository` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work directly with generics, because Generics in C# do not support specialization as C++ Templates do.

The easiest solution would be to perform runtime type-casting, which should be safe since you've tested the value of `T` - thus

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) return group.StringRepository as IRepository<T>;
if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) return group.IntRepository as IRepository<T>;
```

The more common and more thorough solution is design a base interface which is not itself generic, and then implement that interface from the generic one. This is done in the .NET framework with [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)and [`IEnmerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) interfaces, as an example.

Thus:

```
IRepository<T> : IRepository
...
public IRepository GetRepository<T>(RepositoryGroup group)
```